# Relative path to the home directory (linux)

Tags: linux, bash

When I use `pwd` it returns:

```
/home/ahmad/multifit-pretrain-lm/multifit/datasets
```

I look for a command so that I get the path relative to the home directory

```
multifit-pretrain-lm/multifit/datasets
```

Comment: p=$(pwd); echo ${p/"${HOME}/"}   , though it seems like you would want to keep the path in almost every case.

Answer (score 4):

> I look for a command so that I get the path relative to the home directory

You can use bash parameter substitution here:

```
echo "${PWD#"$HOME"/}"
```

- `$PWD` shell variable returns same value as the command `pwd`
- `${PWD#"$HOME"/}` strips `"$HOME"/` at the start from `$PWD`

Answer (score 2):

Variable substitution is a good solution but since you asked for a command, here is one:

```
realpath --relative-base="$HOME" .
```